# Erro ao abrir arquivo em pagina PHP

Tags: php, html, html5

Tenho um página em PHP que lista os arquivos de uma pasta a partir de uma busca. No resultado tem um link para o arquivo afim de abri-lo. Porém, não esta sendo possível abrir os arquivos listados.

**Código index.php**

```
<form name="frmBusca" method="POST" action="buscar.php">

    <input type="text" name="buscar">
    <input type="submit" name="pesquisa" value="Buscar">

</form>
```

**Código buscar.php**

```
    <?php
    //Arquivo para buscar video dentro do explorer
    $video = $_POST['buscar'];

    $endereco = "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/";


    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($endereco);

    foreach ( $iterator as $entry ) {

        if( ($entry->getFilename()) == $video){
            echo $entry->getFilename()," "; 
            $link = $endereco.$entry->getFilename(); 
            echo "<a href='$link'>".$entry->getFilename()."</a>";
            echo "<br>";
        }

    }

?>


<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src='<?php echo $link; ?>' type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

[image: apos listar conteudo]

Comment: O que acontece se clicar no link? E o que deveria fazer esta tag `video` no final do código?

Comment: Apos clicar no link não ocorre nada...nenhum evento!

Comment: E se deixar a variável `$endereco` vazia?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Directory name must not be empty. in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\buscar.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\buscar.php(8): DirectoryIterator->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\buscar.php on line 8

Comment: Óbvio kkk erro meu. Volte o valor da variável e apenas a retire de `$link`. Deixe `$link` apenas com o nome do arquivo.

Comment: Não consigo abrir o arquivo e tão pouco visualiza-lo na tag video!

Comment: $link com nome do arquivo:  OK

Comment: Perfeito tudo funcionando!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correção do arquivo busca.php

```
 <?php
    //Arquivo para buscar video dentro do explorer
    $video = $_POST['buscar'];

    $endereco = "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/";


    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($endereco);

    foreach ( $iterator as $entry ) {

        if( ($entry->getFilename()) == $video){
            echo $entry->getFilename()," "; 
            $link = $entry->getFilename(); 
            echo "<a href='$link' target='_blank'>".$entry->getFilename()."</a>";
            echo "<br>";
        }

    }


?>


<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src='<?php echo $link; ?>' type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

[image: exibicao de video]